# Using properties in Javafx to change style class on button

Tags: javafx-8

I'm trying to update the colour of a JavaFx button based on two attributes. If attribute one is true the button is magenta. If attribute one is false and attribute two is true the button is green otherwise it is red, with the text colour appropriate so that you can read the text. My question is can I do this with a property object which I bind to the button or do I just have to

```
if (attribute_one) {
  button.setStyleClass("magenta-button");
} else if (attribute_two) {
  button.setStyleClass("green-button");
} else {
  button.setStyleClass("red-button");
}
```

In my CSS file I have the three "-button" styles defined.

Comment: How `attribute_one` and `attribute_two` changes?

Comment: They are changed by a press of button or some sort of action.

Comment: You mean `button.setOnAction(event-> doSth())`?